# Rollback recovery for webservices

Tags: logging, distributed-computing, rollback, checkpoint

Im trying to do a Rollback for non-deterministic events(eg: receiving requests to a webservice) There are two approaches i have in my mind, One is checkpoint based, another one is log based. I chose Apache Axis2 platform as my webservice platform.

- So, when we do checkpoint based/log based, do we need to store whole data?
- Is there any difference in storing data in both cases?

Comment: I have done a proof of concept design and implementation for this in axis2. Here is a post about  that.. http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/11/rollback-recovery-for-non-deterministic.html